# как передать параметри в функцию vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Как передать во функцию fetchPosts ище 1 параметр

```
  <wiz-slide>
    <p>{{count}}</p>
    <div class = 'posts' v-for="post in allPosts" :key="post.id">
        <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
        <h2>{{post.email}}</h2>
        <p>{{post.body}}</p>
    </div>
  </wiz-slide>
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  props: ['count'],
  data() {
    return {
      type: 'posts',
      id: '',
      posts: [],
    };
  },
  //   computed: {
  //     allPosts() {
  //       return this.$store.getters.allPosts;
  //     },
  //   },
  computed: mapGetters(['allPosts']),
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['fetchPosts']),
    toggle() {
      console.log(this.count);
      this.fetchPosts(this.count, this.type);
    },
  },
  async mounted() {
    // console.log('22');
    // const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=3');
    // const posts = await res.json();
    // this.posts = posts;
    // this.$store.dispatch('fetchPosts', 2);
    console.log(this.count);
    console.log('i popal');
    console.log(this.type);
  },
  beforeUpdate() {
    this.toggle();
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped></style>
Vuex Сюда передаю
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import actions from './actions';
import mutations from './mutations';

export default () => new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    posts: [],
  },
  actions: {
    async fetchPosts(ctx, limit = 3, comments) {
      const res = await fetch(`${`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${comments}?_limit=`}${limit}`);
      const posts = await res.json();

      ctx.commit('updatePosts', posts);
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    updatePosts(state, posts) {
      state.posts = posts;
    },
  },
  getters: {
    allPosts(state) {
      return state.posts;
    },
  },

  modules: {

  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вообще в экшн передаются 2 параметра. Это, собсно, контекст и нагрузка. Так вот нагрузку лучше передавать одним объектом. Например

```js
async fetchPosts(ctx, { limit: 3, comments: comments, filter: filter }) {
  const res = await fetch(`${`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${comments}?_limit=`}${limit}`);
  const posts = await res.json();
  ctx.commit('updatePosts', posts);
},
```

А в компоненте уже вызывать так

```
methods: {
    ...mapActions(['fetchPosts']),
    toggle() {
      console.log(this.count);
      this.fetchPosts({ limit: this.count, comments: this.type, filter: this.filter });
    },
  },
```

Это избавит в будущем от проблем, когда надо будет менять сигнатуру, например, на бэкэнде. Когда одним объектом приходит это всё-таки удобнее. Да и вообще, вроде как, именно так и говорят делать в доке. Хотя про это могу ошибаться. Но в доке точно есть 2 параметра у экшена. Это контекст и payload. И вот этот пэлоад надо делать объектом. А в этом объекте уже сколько угодно параметров передавать.

Comment: Спасибо,за объяснения!